# How to set the username and password for smtpd in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication

I've set up Postfix as SMTP server by adding this configuration to `main.cf`:

```
myhostname = foo.com
mydomain = foo.com
myorigin = $mydomain

smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination

smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

The `sasl_passwd` file looks like this:

```
foo.com    user:pass
```

And I've generated a `sasl_passwd.db` from that file. Unfortunately, when connecting to my server with the username and password, I keep getting authentication failures. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does Postfix have read permission to the file?

Comment: @ice13berg Yep, chmodding the file with `777` and reloading doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing up `smtpd_sasl` and `smtp_sasl`, the first is for **users authenticating** on your server to submit emails for delivery, the latter is used when postfix does not deliver directly but also through a relay and **postfix itself authenticates**.

> Unfortunately, when connecting to my server with the username and password, I keep getting authentication failures.

You say, that *you* are connecting to the server, so I guess you want to use SASL for smtp**d**. SASL in postfix for user authentication is usually accomplished by using dovecot or cyrus.

Two hints on where to start to face the task you are actually approaching:

- Postfix docs: [SASL_README](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html)
- dovecot docs: [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/)

Comment: I want to use SASL for sending mail from outside my server (e.g. from Thunderbird), is your answer suitable for that?

Comment: My answer faces the problem you described. To accomplish the task you want to solve (use SASL for smtpd), I gave you hints on where to start.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the previous answer, the variable `smtp_sasl_password_maps` only applies to SMTP and not SMTPD. Would that the solution were as simple as pointing Postfix SMTPD to a file.

The previous answer cited what seems like an unnecessary of documentation for the problem of specifying pairs of usernames and passwords to a server. It would be nice if Postfix SMTPD had a way to fall back to a file rather than requiring the administrator to learn about a daemon with pluggable modules.

*Apparently such a solution does not exist, so the problem of specifying a set of usernames and passwords to the Postfix SMTPD configuration becomes a problem of getting Postfix SMTPD to interact with a daemon called SASL.* (This fact, if true, does not appear in the referenced documentation, so I'm taking some risk to claim it here)

I found the most straightforward documentation for getting Postfix SMTPD to interact with SASL here: https://wiki.debian.org/PostfixAndSASL.

I ended up being able to get Postfix SMTPD to recognize the username/password from my shell login using the first method in the above tutorial "Using saslauthd with PAM". This uses the default SASL mechanism "pam" specified in `/etc/default/saslauthd` on Debian (although the tutorial tells you to create a copy of this file just for Postfix, which I did). PAM is a standard Unix authentication framework.

I remember running into some problems even with Debian's documentation, but I can't remember exactly what they were. These two commands were necessary to debug problems I encountered (substitute your own username and password):

```
echo MYPASSWORD | pamtester -v smptd myusername authenticate

sudo testsaslauthd -s smtp -u myusername -p MYPASSWORD
```

I might have had to have `saslauthd` running before Postfix SMTPD would even advertise an ability to authenticate to clients.

Finally, I tested submission using `msmtp` on another host. This tool didn't like the TLS keys in the default Debian Postfix configuration, so I modified `main.cf` to use [letsencrypt](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/secure-postfix-using-lets-encrypt/) keys.

I never had to learn what a Dovecot or a Cyrus is for this solution. However, it would be preferable to have a solution which enables me to use a different password from my shell login, as now my whole system is only as secure as Postfix.